# How to consume node.js service with android

Tags: android, node.js

i have an app that contains buttons ( on /off).
The question is , how to consume a webservice that changes the state of a button..
i need to know the steps to make , so i can consume a node.js servie with my android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the service using HTTP, send a request, parse the response, update your Model/UI accordingly. If your service is actually a REST API you can try to use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: sounds simple , i'm kinda new to this  so i'm not sure how i'm going to do this but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Akramqq Look for some [Retrofit tutorials in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=retrofit+tutorial&oq=retrofit+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8513j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). That should cover the first 3 steps I described. Updating the UI isn't hard but how to do it will depend on your particular use case